# Creating a Pandas dataframe column which is conditional on a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

Say I have some dataframe like below and I create a new column (`track_len`) which gives the length of the column `track_no`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': [1,2,3], 'track_no': ['qwerty23', 'poiu2', 'poiuyt5']})

df['track_len'] = df['track_no'].str.len()
df.head()
```

**My Question is:**

How do I now create a new column (`new_col`) which selects a specific subset of the `track_no` string and outputs that depending on the length of the track number (`track_len`).

I have tried creating a function which outputs the specific string slice of the  `track_no` given the various `track_len` conditions and then use an apply method to create the column and it doesnt work. The code is below:

*Tried*:

```
def f(row):
    if row['track_len'] == 8:
        val = row['track_no'].str[0:3]
    elif row['track_len'] == 5:
        val = row['track_no'].str[0:1]
    elif row['track_len'] =7:
        val = row['track_no'].str[0:2]
    return val

df['new_col'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
df.head()
```

Thus the desired output should be (based on string slicing output of f):

*Output*

```
{new_col: ['qwe', 'p', 'po']}
```

If there are alternative better solutions to this problem those would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function works well you need to remove .str part in your if blocks. Values are already strings:

```
def f(row):
    if row['track_len'] == 8:
        val = row['track_no'][:3]
    elif row['track_len'] == 5:
        val = row['track_no'][:1]
    elif row['track_len'] ==7:
        val = row['track_no'][:2]
    return val

df['new_col'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
df.head()

#Output: 

    item_id track_no    track_len   new_col
0   1       qwerty23    8           qwe
1   2       poiu2       5           p
2   3       poiuyt5     7           po
```

Comment: Ah thank you mate! When you say the values are already strings you mean the `track_no` column values right? So we can slice it without having to `.str`?

Comment: Yes you can slice them without casting (converting to string)